# prettyPhoto with knockOut

Tags: knockout.js, prettyphoto

I'm using knockoutjs to bind data from server for a photo gallery. When I use prettyphoto with this gallery it does not work.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gcontent" data-bind="with: gList">
        <ul id="plist" class="thumbs"  data-bind="foreach: rows">
            <li class="dd">                    
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img width="140" height="100"  data-bind="attr:{src: '/Uploads/media/Images/'+Id+Pic, alt:Title }">
                    <div class="thumbcon">
                        <div class="con">
                            <a data-bind="attr:{href: '/Uploads/media/Images/'+Id+Pic, title:Title}" rel='prettyPhoto[gallery]'>
                                show</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: define "does not work" ? any concrete errors anywhere?

Comment: if you click the link, it opens the image in browser not showing it in modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that someone else is facing the same problem. The problem was that ajax is not finishing and the data is not ready before calling prettyPhoto .. to fix it you have to wait until the ajax call finish.

example:

```
$.getJSON(_serviceURL(), function (data) {
if (data != null) {
......
$(document).ready(function () {$("area[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();}                    
else {
......
}
});
```

Comment: The best practice would be to place `$("area[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();` to a function and call that function from the jSON call. You don't need the document.ready() for this.